# Behaviour for significant change location API when terminated/suspended?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, uiapplicationdelegate, ios-app-suspended-state

This is the section from the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) documentation describing the app behavior with [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges):

> If you start this service and your
>   application is subsequently
>   terminated, the system automatically
>   relaunches the application into the
>   background if a new event arrives. In
>   such a case, the options dictionary
>   passed to the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method of your application delegate
>   contains the key
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey
>   to indicate that your application was
>   launched because of a location event.
>   Upon relaunch, you must still
>   configure a location manager object
>   and call this method to continue
>   receiving location events. When you
>   restart location services, the current
>   event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location
>   property of your location manager
>   object is populated with the most
>   recent location object even before you
>   start location services.

So my understanding is that if your app terminates (and I assume if you don't call [stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) from [applicationWillTerminate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:)) you will get woken up with a [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey) parameter to [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:). At that point you create your [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), call [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) and do your background location processing for a [limited time](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8).  So I am fine with this bit.

The previous paragraph only talks about what happens when the app is terminated, it doesn't suggest what you do when the application is suspended.  The documentation for [didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) says:

> The application tracks location
>   updates in the background, was purged,
>   and has now been relaunched. In this
>   case, the dictionary contains a key
>   indicating that the application was
>   relaunched because of a new location
>   event.

Suggesting that you will only receive this call when your app is launched (because of a location change) after you have been terminated.

However the paragraph on the [Significant Change Service](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) has the following to say:

> If you leave this service running and
>   your application is subsequently
>   suspended or terminated, the service
>   automatically wakes up your
>   application when new location data
>   arrives. At wake-up time, your
>   application is put into the background
>   and given a small amount of time to
>   process the location data. Because
>   your application is in the background,
>   it should do minimal work and avoid
>   any tasks (such as querying the
>   network) that might prevent it from
>   returning before the allocated time
>   expires. If it does not, your
>   application may be terminated.

This suggests you are woken up with location data if your app has been suspended, but fails to mention how you are woken up:

- Does the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate) get a callback telling me that I am resuming from a suspended state into a background state?
- Does the location manager (that was freeze dried when the app was suspended) start receiving [locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:) callbacks?
- Do I just need to implement code in my [didUpdateToLocation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:) message which checks the application state and does minimal processing if in background mode?

In the process of writing this up, I think I may have just answered my own question, but it would be great to have my understanding of this confirmed by someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: can you clarify what does 'freeze dried' mean?

Comment: @honey I apologise for the mediocre metaphor. What I meant at the time is that the state of the location manager is saved as at the moment the app is suspended. Not sure if this is still the case. It's been a while :).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Since I asked this question, I have done a fair bit of testing (mostly on the train between home and work) and have confirmed that the behaviour for suspended apps is as I suspected at the end of the question.

That is, your suspended app is woken up, you don't receive any callbacks on your app delegate, instead you receive your location updates through your existing [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate?language=objc).  You can detect that you are running in the background by checking the *applicationState*, and do limited work for the case where you are woken from a suspended state to do location processing.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground
```

I came to this conclusion with a location test harness that you are welcome to [download](http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?id=1480) and try out.  It is a pretty simple app that allows you to turn on significant change and GPS change APIs through the UI and log all the responses that you get back.

**N.B.** Point six in the previous answer is not correct. *Freeze dried* suspended apps do receive *CLLocationManagerDelegate* callbacks when they are woken up from a suspended state.

Comment: Struck out #6 in my answer so as not to confuse people.

Comment: Ironically, I also felt the same confusion when developing for the significant change. I still have some doubts on what happens if the app is closed. does the UIApplicationDelegate callback's won't happen? is that the right way to start the app. if the location manager has not yet been fired up, how can it get the notifications in background? (time for some more R&D)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample app, it was very useful for me. I have a question: What if I was using the standard location service in the background, not the significant one, will the app also be relaunched after termination in that case? I asked this question here in detail, I'd be glad if you could lighten me up :] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239967/will-ios-wake-up-the-terminated-app-if-its-registered-with-location-for-uibackg

Comment: Not worked on ios7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7

Comment: @RedBlueThing have one query can we call API (to update server lat long) at the time of App is in kill mode ?

Comment: @BhaveshDhaduk Haven't used these APIs for a long time, but yes, you can definitely create networks requests when launched from a cold start.

Answer (score 26):

My understanding is as follows (I'm in the process of writing an application that relies on this API, but haven't completed this component enough to start testing):

1. Your application is run for the first time, you register to **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**, and provide a callback function. While your application is running, it will call that callback whenever it receives a significant change.
2. If your application is put to the background, UIApplication will receive **applicationWillResignActive**, followed by **applicationDidEnterBackground**.
3. If your application is killed while it is suspended, you will not be notified; however, if your application is killed while it is running (foreground or background to my knowledge), you will get a moment with **applicationWillTerminate**. You cannot request extra background time from this function.
4. Despite being killed in the background, the OS will relaunch your application. If your application is simply launched by the OS for a change, you will get a call to **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```objectivec
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey])
```

will help you determine if you've come back from a background location change.

5. If, instead, you were currently running in the background, and your app is manually relaunched by the user, you will receive an **applicationWillEnterForeground** followed by **applicationDidBecomeActive**.
6. <s>Regardless of how it happened, when your application is relaunched (unless it was still running in the background as a result of a background task and said task had started monitoring changes), you need to explicitly tell it to **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** again because the callback is no longer attached after "freeze drying." And yes, you just need to implement code in didUpdateToLocation once you've re-attached a location handler of some kind once coming back from the suspended state.</s>

This is what I'm going on with my code development right now. As I mentioned before, I'm not quite ready to test this on a device so I can't tell if I've interpreted everything correctly, so commenters, please feel free to correct me (though I've done substantial reading on the topic).

Oh, and if by some stroke of bad luck, you release an app that does what I want mine to do, I might cry :)

Good luck!

Comment: @Tegeril +1 Thanks for the answer. I was starting to hear crickets on this one. :) I am surprised that apps started from being suspended need to re-call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.  Do you have a link to the doco where this is described? My understanding was that being loaded from a suspended state will instantiate all your objects as they were when the app was suspended. So I would expect the significant change request to be in effect.

Comment: You might be talking about this? "Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this method to continue receiving location events" But I think this is referring to the case where you app launched from a terminated state (by a location event). This is basically the root of my question, 'what happens for the suspended case?'.

Comment: Morgan Grainger on the Dev forums suggested this: "You need to create a CLLocationManager, set a delegate, and call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when your application is launched, or else Core Location will have nowhere to deliver the updates." in the context of restarting an application regardless of from a terminated or suspended state. From "app was relaunched after startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and now what?"

Comment: I agree that this could still be vague even in the context of that forum post (the poster was discussing waking from background, but Morgan used the more general restarting of an application). I still think you need to call to monitor again when your application relaunches if you want to work with the significant changes function. If you want to instead launch a background task and update with the standard location service and GPS functionality, that is an alternative option. I don't believe you need to reregister on each launch with significant changes in order to be launched again though.

Comment: @Tegeril I guess it depends on how you interpret "relaunched". To me this implies from a terminated state. The statement about Core Location not knowing where to deliver updates makes perfect sense to me in that context. But when you are launched from a suspended state it will thaw out a CCLocationManager object which is hooked up to core location already (like every other object that is thawed out, it should just work). Sounds like I need to try this out :P. I'll let you know what I find out.  Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Tegeril Heh :) Hopefully.  Might be time to go on a train ride to test this out.  Debugging while walking around is tricky.

Comment: Yeah, most of the discussion I read about testing this involved coercing someone into driving around for an hour while the developer sat in the passenger seat with the phone and a laptop. Not exactly ideal!

Comment: @Tegeril Yep. This is the one piece of the documentation that should be totally clear. Testing this stuff is tricky. I tried debugging on the train this morning with the app suspended and didn't get any callbacks.  I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if I was just attached to one cell for the entire time.  I have to test the same area with the app running to check.

Comment: @Tegeril Thanks again for your answer. Seem my answer for details on how this stuff works for suspended apps. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I'm glad something definitive came out of this, should help me in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

If the application is evoked from suspended state as a result of  location change application will launch in background state.

All the objects will be live and you will recieve location update in the existing delegate.

Answer (score 0):

So I just have an important note specific to when app was terminated:

For some APIs that can **launch** the app in the background and later need to be receiving a callback that handles that launching, would likely need a `delegate` object to be set.

So if you get an *app launch* (i.e. from terminated state, not suspended state) because of location tracking then, your locationManager delegate callbacks won't be called unless you set the delegate in the `didFinishLaunching`. To be more precise, you won't get any delegate callbacks until you set your delegate.

1. So if you're doing follow in your ABC viewcontroller after your app launch

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.delegate = self
```

2. Then app got terminated
3. Then app was location due to a location change in the background
4. YOU WON'T GET a callback until you foreground the app and open your ABC viewcontroller

It's incorrect to think that the app magically knows what the delegate object is. It doesn't *persist* that information.

Solution:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
   let myLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
   myLocationManager.delegate = self
}
```

I figured this out for a totally unrelated API:

```
optional func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                      didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

That is, if you don't set your delegate before AppLaunch, then you miss user interaction with the notifications that happen immediately after an app termination. To be more precise you miss any callbacks until you set the userNotification's delegate.