# Example for startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I am new to iPhone programming. I am looking for an example or a demo on how to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method with the `CoreLocation` Manager.

I am confused by the documentation because, I am not sure if the same delegate method is called as in the case of invoking `startUpdatingLocation`. (i.e. the delegate `locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation: (CLLocation *)oldLocation` is called)

Any help on this would be appreciated. Also, I am testing it on the simulator by subclassing of `CLLocationManager`. This subclass provides a simulation of location services when running on the iPhone Simulator. Is there a better way to test this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have done a bit of testing with the significant change API.  I posted a [sample project on GitHub](http://github.com/redbluething/LocationTest) that lets you play with regular and significant location updates.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421242/behaviour-for-significant-change-location-api-when-terminated-suspended) might also shed some light on what happens when you get woken up for a significant change event.

**Update**

Another thing you should be aware of, there is a [bug in CoreLocation in 4.1](http://github.com/redbluething/LocationTest). Basically if your app is in the background, then it will crash when core location tries to wake you up. It is fixed in 4.2.

Comment: Thanks cannonade! I will check that sample project.

Comment: @mark No problems. If you find either of the two answers useful, please vote them up and if a particular answer resolves your issue you can select it as the "accepted answer". Good luck :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputations to vote the answer. But I marked the answer as the accepted answer. Thanks again. The sample app was really helpful. Do you have significant experience in working with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges? I am asking this because I am newbie trying something ambitious. I am running into issues like this because of limited documentation.

Comment: @Mark Yep. I had the same problems (hence the linked question). I was making some progress, but the bug in iOS 4.1 has put a damper on my dev efforts till 4.2 comes out.

Comment: I think 4.2 is out now. I mean at least the developer preview. Hope the bug is fixed.

Comment: FYI: The URL to the GitHub example project is changed to https://github.com/RedBlueThing/LocationTest

Answer (score 1):

There is a great video session on these new iOS 4.0 CoreLocation and MapKit features from WWDC 2010 that should be freely available in iTunes U for all registered iPhone developers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason! I am a registered developer but I did not pay the $99. Can I still access these files?

Comment: Not sure about that. See if you can log into iTunes with your developer account and get them. Or log into the ADC and see if there's a link.