# Background tasks iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

I am trying to implement location updates in the background based on a timer. I know all about the different location updating methods in iOS and have tried them but they don't fit the need. I need to check locations every so often even while not active. I've tried using timers but they don't execute in the background. That led me to find this question [How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application) and it mentions using

```
UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
```

My questions is how do you use this method? I've searched the apple docs but they are recursively pointing at each other when dealing with background execution and location updates with no examples.

I have this code now based on some examples I've found:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    locationUpdater=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:locationUpdater];
        locationUpdater=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    } ];
}
```

And I have added the key "location" in the .plist for supported background modes

Does adding this just guarantee that my application won't be killed for some certain amount of time so I can keep a timer running? or where do I add the methods that are to get executed while in the background mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background task runs longer than 10 minutes, your app will be terminated.

You really should use the os location services instead to get notified about location changes. Why is that not enough? If location doesn't change, what's the point of retrieving it over and over again, and once it changes, you'll be notified.

Comment: the time interval and more the distance between updates are not accurate enough for my needs. Obviously I will just be restarting the timer if I don't need the location. Is the background task just like normal execution? Do you put that code in the didEnterBackground ?

Comment: There's a location manager "navigation" mode that is supposedly quite accurate even for displaying real-time location when driving in a car - are you using that? Or do you need it for airplane speeds? Background task is like normal execution, yes, but if you abuse it the app will either be killed by OS or even rejected by the review team.

Comment: So, what if I create a timer in this background task that sends a request on every minute? After ten minutes my app will be terminated? If so, i can destroy and again create that background task every time my timer gets invalidated. Am i wrong?

Comment: Timers will not fire when the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

For conceptual understanding have a look [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/).

For a detailed analysis of the accuracy you can visit [this](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/#more-480)

you should start using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. You can find the sample code reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917492/example-for-startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges)