# CLLocation Manager should start updating location automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, cllocationmanager

I am developing an app which uses `CLLocationManager` to track user's current location.

As soon as I launch app, it works well till the end of the day, I used to get the user's location till evening 5'o clock.

I want my app to start automatically on the next day morning, without launching the app but my app is running in the background.
I just want to work like alarm manager in android. Any suggestions?

I want CLLocationManager to startUpdatingLocation even when the device is rebooted without launching the app [while switching off the device, the app is running in background]

How to implement this?

Comment: "startUpdateLocation" method call only if you are between time.

Comment: @mindfreak Yes, we need to call startUpdatingLocation, but even I reboot the iphone, it should start automatically without launching. Where I should call the method even the app is running in background.

Comment: @Daij-Djan yeah sure. I am checking. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS *will* relaunch apps that sign up for location changes! This works under ios6 already! BUT to the background only. So that the location can be tracked

> > see e.g. the 'Moves' app that will track your location

the idea is that you're app wakes to the background mode.

see:

- [Will iOS wake up the terminated app if it's registered with location for UIBackgroundModes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239967/will-ios-wake-up-the-terminated-app-if-its-registered-with-location-for-uibackg)

pay attention to:

- [App won't relaunch when monitoring CLLocationManager significant location changes  - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134039/app-wont-relaunch-when-monitoring-cllocationmanager-significant-location-change)

compare with:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do what you want with iOS 6 or lower (app can't launch itself on those iOS versions), workaround would be to alarm user to launch your app with local notifications. But iOS 7 comes with some new features, and allows certain apps to wake at the background to complete tasks.

Comment: My question is not about the launching of the app by itself. I want to start tracking location automatically even when the app is in background on next day , or even the device is rebooted without launching the app.

Comment: I don't think that without user interaction you can do that. And, I well understood your question.

Comment: Yeah OK Understand. Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

You can not make startUpdatingLocation(didUpdateLocations) automatically run after reboot. You have to 
1. use startMonitoringForRegion ;
2. or use a remote notification to invoke startUpdatingLocation.