# iphone location method startMonitoringSignificantChanges fails to work

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, gps, multitasking

i am developing an application for iphone using iOS 4.2 SDK.
My application need to popup an alert when a user arrives a specific location (in 400m radius). Note that I need to get this alert even if the app is in the **background**.

When I use the locationManager with **startUpdatingLocation** mode, i get the alert when the app is in the foreground, but not when it is in the background.
When I try to run with locationManager with **startMonitoringSignificantChanges** mode, i don't get any position changes in background and even not in foreground (i.e. didUpdateLocation method is never called. only once in the application start up)
some facts:
1. I updated info.plist with UIBackgroundMode with 'location' as first item in array.
2. I updated info.plist UIDeviceCapabilities with gps and location-services (though it doesn't really matters)
3. all said above refers to running this app on the 3GS iphone device.
4. I tried this app on sdk 4.0 and 4.1 and got the same problem. 
5. The device supports startMonitoringSignificantChanges use (method of locationManager confirms it)
6. When I check the app on the device i move in range of ~150 meters meters. Is the startMonitoringSignificantChanges will call didUpdateLocation method with this kind of movement?
 
7. All settings on the devices are turned to on mode (roaming, 3G, wifi,...) 

Am i missing something? any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: still didn't find answer ... help.. anyone?

Answer (score 0):

if you're still interested, have a look at that post:
[Behaviour for significant change location API when terminated/suspended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421242/behaviour-for-significant-change-location-api-when-terminated-suspended)

and the example project mentioned:
http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?id=1480