# iPhone: stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when app quits

Tags: iphone, background, core-location

I want to stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when the user is killing the app from the multitask bar (switch bar) like the Waze GPS App does.

(i also want to cancel all LocalNotifications)

the problem is, that after an application get's suspended, applicationWillTerminate doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Waze does it is by running the NORMAL LOCATION SERVICE in background, not the "significant location service".
a special option that can be set in the plist file.

there is no way to close the Low Power mode of location services - "Significant location service" when the user kills the app, because it was not intended to be used this way.

I guess I will simply have to follow apple's standards using significant location service.

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at this post: [Behaviour for significant change location API when terminated/suspended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421242/behaviour-for-significant-change-location-api-when-terminated-suspended/3446140)

Lots of interesting things in it.
In particular, you should stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges on entering background and register for significant location changes with a Service

Comment: you probably meant stopUpdatingLocation and startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, both on entering background. I already read that whole post, it does clear some things up, but not my issue.