# iOS 4 application lifecycle behavior of standard location service running in background

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm working on a location tracking application that uses both the standard location service and significant change location service in the background (my app is registered for background location updates in iOS 4+) as applicable. Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421242/behaviour-for-significant-change-location-api-when-terminated-suspended) I have a solid understanding of how significant change comes back from the background state and relaunches from a terminated state. However, I'm still not clear on how the standard location service behaves in these instances. Could anyone break down the exact behavior of the standard location service running in the background?
Specifically:

1. How does the standard location service behave when you leave it running and the app suspends into the background? From my own testing, I've seen that it will continue waking up to receive callbacks on `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (I have it send the location out a socket and I can see it on the network). Is there a time or memory limit for this callback to process?
2. Does the standard location service continue to run even when my app is terminated? That is, will it ever relaunch with `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` the way the significant change service does? I assume it the `CLLocationManager` would also need to be restarted in this case, as the significant change service does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to both 1 & 2, If you have registered your app as using background location then your app does not get terminated and continues to run in the background until you do this:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

So, there is no time or memory limit however there is a battery limit. If your battery is low, all apps using gps will be closed. Since your app is not terminated in normal circumstances, either it is not required to or it does not relaunch (after being terminated coz of battery) with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`

Standard and significant services are different in this manner that significant wakes up the app whenevr there is a location update but standard makes app run continuously and hence drain battery.

Before you choose what service to use consider reading the [Location-Awareness Programming guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: 1. I meant is there a time or memory limit _for the callback to process_. The thrust of the question is how much time and memory can I take while servicing a background location update.
2. Significant-change is capable of doing more than simply waking up an application, it's capable of relaunching an application that has been completely terminated by the OS. I've seen significant-change persist through restarting the iPhone and enabling and disabling location services. My question is if standard location services ever behave like this, which in my experience they do not.