# How does Skype keep sending notifications after 10 minutes on the iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cryptography, skype

I've noticed something odd about Skype on the iPad. It keeps sending me notifications with the contents of what people have sent to me as text even after I've closed the app. For the first ten minutes it makes sense as that's how long something can keep running in the background after you close an app. These are local notifications. However beyond that it should simply not be possible. Skype has claimed for ages that their connections are end to end encrypted. For them to keep sending these notifications after ten minutes means that they are sending them via Apple's push notification service. Which means that somehow they are decrypting messages I receive on their servers and sending them to my device via Apple. This seems like either clear evidence of there being no end to end encryption or that they have a deal with Apple allowing them to keep running for more than ten minutes. If it's the latter, is there some way to do this in my own app?

Comment: Clearly off-topic ... or maybe not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this post describes answer in more details: [iOS: Keep an app running like a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044095/ios-keep-an-app-running-like-a-service)

Also here (search for UIBackgroundModes):
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 3):

Certain classes of apps are allowed to keep running in the background. This include GPS apps and VOIP apps, among others. See the docs for the `UIBackgroundModes` Info.plist key.