# How to sync data in iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, synchronization

I am new to ios programming,I want to sync data between mobile and app server, In android lot of  ways are there to sync data similarly in ios I want to know different ways to sync data between mobile and app server, for every 12 hours I want to run sync service which takes care offline data storage.

Comment: plz elaborate your question, post some code.

Comment: every 12 hours i want sync data with server either push or pull from server,i didn't find any way in ios ,one thing i can do it with push notifications,schedule timer is there any other way

Comment: Maybe store the "next time to sync" as an NSDate using NSUserDefaults?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc

Check if that stored date has expired each time the app becomes active. If it hasn't fire a timer in case the update point happens while the app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

make a singleton class make a GET api call and update ur local data or database accordingly as per requirement.

Comment: every 12 hours i want sync data with server either push or pull from server,i didn't find any way in ios ,one thing i can do it with push notifications,schedule timer is there any other way

Comment: what u can do is u can update ur data while u start ur app. also u can try to implement some services to achieve ur data syncing. read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044095/ios-keep-an-app-running-like-a-service