# Check Wi-Fi network change in background in iOS like blynkmyplant iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, iot, reachability

There is an app [Blynkmyplant](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blynk-myplant/id1163620518?mt=8), I am interested in one of the functionality that this app can do, whereas my iOS app is not allowed to do. When blynkmyplant app open iOS settings and user changes Wi-Fi network, a local notification is displayed up immediately. How can this app monitor network change in background?

Apple reachability does not work in background, I have already tried it, also tried SCNetwork but does not seem to work in my iOS application. I have searched everywhere but all answers says that in background we cannot listen to network changes, my app has background modes also, but still cannot get network change block called.

Comment: This can be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044095/ios-keep-an-app-running-like-a-service

Comment: @CynichniyBandera Yes, that's what all I have read. Then how Blynkmyplant app manages to do this? that's my aim to find out.

Comment: I suspect it uses either timers or something like constant location updates as a carrier that keeps it alive and then does something more, like checking network connection. Also network connection can be checked not only directly by trying to connect some IP, system may have some kind of trick that allows to know if network is available without connecting. I would dig towards this ) Good luck!