# On which iOS devices exactly is region monitoring supported?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, device, regions, clregion

From what I can interpret from the runtime requirements of [sample region monitoring code of Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726), region monitoring is available on iPhone 4, iPad 2 Wifi + 3G or later. So I'm assuming that it's not available on iPad1 with 3G, or iPhone 3G/3GS.

Is this a correct interpretation? I cannot test this since I don't have all those devices and I couldn't find an official documentation about this.

PS: I know that I can check for it in the code by calling `regionMonitoringAvailable` method but I need this information to decide for the architecture of my app, so I need to know this upfront.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I have learned from working on region monitoring enabled devices is that you are correct.

Currently, region monitoring is only supported on the following devices (running iOS 5.x).

- iPhone 4
- iPhone 4S
- iPhone 5
- iPad 2, 3, and 4 (new iPad) 3G/4G
- iPad 3 and 4 (new iPad) Wifi
- (would love some feedback for region monitoring on iPod Touch models)

I was told at WWDC that with the advent of the location tiles in iOS 6, that region monitoring would be coming to ALL iOS 6 devices. However, my testing so far has only garnered me the Wifi enabled iPad 3. I haven't been able to test on the iPhone 3GS yet, but I'm not holding my breath. It may be possible that they will enable this in a later beta or at launch, but I'm not optimistic.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Supported devices for Region Monitoring has less to do with iOS version and more to do with the hardware. That is why, for example, the 3GS doesn't support it (although one might think the 3GS would support it): the hardware doesn't support it.

Comment: I understand the hardware aspect of it. But the changes to location tiles (iOS 6), basically any device with a wifi antenna will be able to use region monitoring. No GPS hardware needed. I've done my homework on this, I'm just trying to reach out and get confirmation on devices I don't have access to.

Comment: Thank you guys. After iOS6 is launched maybe we can test some devices and add more answers here to make things more clear for everyone.

Comment: For what it's worth, wifi only iPad 3 on iOS 6.0.1 returns YES for CLLocation's +regionMonitoringAvailable.

Comment: Yes, I should update this list. The latest iPad (the New iPad) supports region monitoring as well.

Comment: i have iPAd 2 but it gives me region monitoring not available on this device , when i am checking it.

Comment: iPod 4, 6.1.3, region monitoring not available.

Comment: iPod 4, 6.1.3 significant location change also not available.  Looks like it is only the newer wifi only hardware that supports this tech.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere ? exactly which one supports and which not?