# Wake up an app at a specific time in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to build an application that will have an alarm clock function - meaning that the user will be able to set a time for the application to wake up and perform some actions.

I saw that i can post and catch a local push notification but i need to run some code when the application wakes up.

Does iOS offer this behavior? 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible this might help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239967/will-ios-wake-up-the-terminated-app-if-its-registered-with-location-for-uibackg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know there is no such behavour in iOS.

It is possible to catch a push notification as you mentioned. And you can run your code in 
 `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` or `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` methods in application delegate class.

more info on [notifications:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

Comment: This would be the most precise method. You can send a transparent push which will wake your app up, but not present the user a UI message.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't wake up an App locally. But in iOS7 it's now possible to perform some tasks like downloading stuff from the internet when the App receives a silent push. But this requirers a server which is sending the push.

But you can wake up your App if the device enters or leaves a given region.

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 4 you can use local notifications for this purpose, but note that the app will  launch or return from background and execute code only if user opens the notification. There is no way to bypass this behaviour.