# Swift Background Execution at certain time each morning

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I am trying to run a particular function with background execution at a certain time each  morning. Here's what I have figured out...

```
func getCurrentTime() { //Is called every minuite by a timer
    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    var stringValue = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    if stringValue == "7:00 AM" {
        sendPushAlert()//Defined elsewhere in code, executes desired code
    }
}
```

However, that does not run in the background (e.g. when app not open), and seems like a clunky way to do things.

So, How do I run background execution at a certain time each morning?

Or, is there a better way to fetch data to show in a push notification?

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: See also: [Wake up an app at a specific time in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708798/wake-up-an-app-at-a-specific-time-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force iOS to launch your app at a specific time.

If all you want to do is send a notification at a specific time, [schedule a local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html). If the user opens your notification then your app will launch.

Comment: I don't need to open my app, I just want a push notification to be sent at 7. However, before the push notification is sent, it needs to complete some logic (Fetching and parsing a number to have in the push notification). How do I do this?

Comment: You'll have to do that on the server side. You can't schedule work to be completed at a specific time on the client side.

Comment: The link you posted seems to suggest that one can schedule a local "transparent" notification that is not seen, but "wakes up" the app and could let it send a local push notification with the updated data. Is this correct? If so, if you could post an answer describing how, I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You can create silent push (remote) notifications, but you cannot schedule a silent local notification.