# Sequence of events for CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, uiapplicationdelegate

I was reading up on [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method and came across the following code from [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/launch-options/):

```
@import CoreLocation;

@interface AppDelegate () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Location Services Disabled", nil)
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.", nil)
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

I've already looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421242/behaviour-for-significant-change-location-api-when-terminated-suspended), but I am still confused about the sequence of events. Correct me if I'm wrong:

When an app is launched for the first time, the `CLLocationManager` gets set-up (if the location services are enabled) and it starts monitoring for the significant changes in location. When the app is subsequently terminated, does the `CLLocationManager` keep monitoring for the changes? As far as I can tell, it does not. Then how does it get launched if there is a new location event? I know that next the app gets relaunched with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` passed to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Is it done in the background? Now the `CLLocationManager` will get set-up (again) first, and right after that the `locationManager` will start updating the location as per event. After that the `CLLocationManager` will keep monitoring for the changes.

Related question: what delegate does get called when there is a new location event and the app is running (either in the background or foreground)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When the app is subsequently terminated, does the CLLocationManager keep monitoring for the changes?* 
-> you guess is right. **it's No**, but your os monitors and knows that this application might need it because you called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`:.

**your question** -*I know that next the app gets relaunched with UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey passed to application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Is it done in the background?*

Ans-> **yes**,

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system -automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your application delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your application was launched because of a location event.

*what delegate does get called when there is a new location event and the app is running (either in the background or foreground)?*

The link you provided says everything. when your app is running in foreground or backGround, and if a new location event arrives , and your app app to become active,still your  `CLLocationManagerDelegate` will get called.